# Screen Reading wordpress plugin

Tags: wordpress, plugins, accessibility, screen-readers

Currently working on a wheelchair transit website using WordPress. they want to incorporate a read website button in the nav. Does anyone know a plugin or a way to have this button read the entire site when it is clicked.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this is what you are looking for:

https://wordpress.org/plugins/responsivevoice-text-to-speech/

Solutions like this seem highly questionable to me, for several reasons:

1. Non-sighted and low-vision users will likely already be using something more robust, like JAWS, VoiceOver, or NVDA.
2. I see this as more of a solution for sighted users who *can* read the page but would find it more convenient to have it read aloud.
3. Something like this may even be confusing to non-sighted users who are already using another screen reader.
4. Standalone screen readers (like JAWS, VoiceOver, or NVDA) are highly configurable by the end-user. On-page readers probably aren't nearly as comprehensive in their configuration options. What configuration options exist are are likely set by the developer and are non-adjustable for end-users.
5. Standalone screen readers typically have better community support and receive more frequent software updates than WordPress plugins.

Comment: Thank you, I've tried this one but it only reads paragraphs that you apply it to. I'm looking for one that reads the entire website. I agree with all your points the client, however, doesn't.